# Low opacity background/fills on Cinder cause the screen to flash red

Tags: opengl, cinder

When I try to draw a low opacity background over my content in Cinder, my screen flashes in red in the beginning then keeps flickering while the content is drawn.

I'm trying to replicate an effect I used in Processing/p5.js where the background isn't fully opaque so objects appear to be moving "fading":

```
gl::enableAlphaBlending();
gl::color( ColorA(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.05f) );
gl::drawSolidRect( getWindowBounds() );
```

I researched this could be an OpenGL issue however I'm a beginner C++/Cinder/OpenGL user so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to fix my issue by using:

```
CINDER_APP( spaintApp, RendererGl( RendererGl::Options().msaa( 4 ) ) )
```